# Is it wrong to charge a laptop/cellphone battery when the device is on?

Tags: batteries, cellphone, laptop

I always try to charge my laptop or my smartphone after turning them off. I feel that leaving these devices charging when they are on could be detrimental to them.

But... is it? And whether the question is "yes" or "no", what would be the electrical reasoning behind that answer?

I believe that (almost) every battery in these devices are lithuim-ion ones nowadays, so the question would be oriented to this kind specifically.

Comment: How would the battery know the device was on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are SOME things that won't operate while you are charging them. My nice Sony noise-cancelling Blue-Tooth headphones just automatically power down when you plug in the USB cable to charge them.

But most things will continue to operate if you plug them in to charge the battery. Most (all?) cell phones I've ever seen. Certainly there are those of us who have no land-line (only cell phones) who depend on our phones operating even when we are at home (or at the office, or in the car) and charging.

Now, some equipment may charge more slowly during operating, because some of the power you are putting into it goes towards actually operating the gadget.  But unless there is an explicit warning or automatic behavior, IMHO, it is safe to assume that you can continue operating something during charging.

Comment: Also, the fact that some devices don't let you charge and use it at the same time is a design choice - not a technical limitation. The battery itself doesn't really care whether you're using it at the same time as you're charging it.

Comment: This is slightly tangential, but there are two main types of charger IC's out there for USB chargeable devices. There are those that have a separate connection for the battery, and can therefore isolate it during charging, and those which have a single connection for battery and system load. The latter kind is cheaper, but really needs the load to be powered off during charging for best performance. This may be part of the explanation for the blue-tooth device.